# AWS How to associate a VPC interface endpoint to a specific NLB in another VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have an existing VPC interface endpoint for elastic load balancer in a VPC A and a NLB in VPC B with a VPC endpoint service associated.

How I can create the association between the VPC interface endpoint and NLB as in the AWS diagram?

[image]

According to [I can't connect to an endpoint service from my Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (Amazon VPC) interface endpoint using AWS PrivateLink.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDGB7.png), it looks a request needs to be created.

> .
>   Request that the endpoint service provider accepts the endpoint connection request to activate the connection.

However, I do not see any option to create a request in the VPC endpoint side.

[image]

According to [Create A VPC Endpoint Service](https://cloudaffaire.com/create-a-vpc-endpoint-service/), the request can be created when creating a VPC interface endpoint, but I have already created one.

Please advise how to, or correct me if I misunderstand something.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your `VPC Dashboard` > `Endpoint Service` and check under the `Endpoint Connections` tab. If your VPC endpoint is in the list and the state is `Available`, then the association you are looking for is established.

One possible reason why you did not have a `Pending acceptance` status in your VPC endpoint could be that you did not check the `Acceptance required` box when creating the VPC endpoint service.

Check out [AWS New York Summit 2018 - AWS PrivateLink: Fundamentals (SRV211)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=20RxEzAXG9o) at 28:08 and 33:33 for the full demo.